# IOError: [Errno 13] when installing virtualwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper, errno, ioerror

After successfully installling virtualenv in terminal with 'pip install virtualenv', I tried installing virtualwrapper  with 'pip install virtualenvwrapper' and something seems to have gone wrong with some code presenting in red instead of the usual white. There was about 20-30 lines of code in essence it said the following:

Installing collected packages: virtualenv-clone, pbr, stevedore, virtualenvwrapper

Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

Then there is a list of file paths shown, followed by..

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/clonevirtualenv.py'

[image: see screenshot of the code for more detail]

Does anyone know what could have gone wrong and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when it's about permission problem you have try with sudo(super user).

if Linux,

`$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`

if Windows,

open cmd with administration privilege and then,

`pip install virtualenvwrapper`

Comment: I was wondering about whether or not to use sudo. should I install virtualenv with sudo and install virtualenvwrapper without sudo?  If I have already installed these without sudo do I need to uninstall them first? also I am wondering if part of the issue is that I need to be setting an appropriate directory location for the programs to install in

Comment: I tried to sudo pip install virtualenv and got the following message The directory '/home/rf/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: I then tried sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper and got the following error The directory '/home/rf/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenvwrapper (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenvwrapper

Comment: If you dislike to install with sudo then use `virtualenv` or `virtualwrapper`. It's the easy and efficient solution.

Comment: I am happy to install with Sudo if that is required. I want to install it the correct way. I'm just unsure if the reason I can't  install virtualenvwrapper because I installed virtualenv without sudo

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall virtualenv

```
# you might need to use sudo depending on how you installed it
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

Then, install virtualenvwrapper with sudo

```
sudo pip install virtualenwrapper
```

Since virtualenvwrapper has virtualenv among its dependencies, it will take care of installing it - no need to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that sounds like it would be a good solution however I am wondering if I still need to do this now as I successfully installed virtualenvwrapper with "pip install virtualenvwrapper -user" and no errors came up. I am wondering though if it's ok that neither virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper have been installed with sudo. Will I run into problems when I try using the programs or have i installed it correctly as is. If so I won't change it otherwise I will try your idea

Comment: I think it might work, but I've never tried myself, so it's a bit hard to say whether you will encounter issues later on @RFb

Comment: Ok. if I run into problems I will uninstall both virtualenvwrapper and virtualenv and reinstall using sudo. Hopefully it works, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should install virtualenvwrapper via system package manager.

Either `dnf install python-virtualenvwrapper` on Fedora or `apt-get install virtualenvwrapper` on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your reply that probably would have been easier but installed now. I have lubuntu